# Is the functor $\mathrm{op} \colon \mathcal{C} \longrightarrow \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ equal to the identity?

Tags: category-theory

In Kashiwara-Schapira (Categories and abelian sheaves), it is written

1. A contravariant functor from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal{C}'$ is a functor from $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ to $\mathcal{C}'$.
2. It is convenient to introduce the contravariant functor $\mathrm{op} \colon \mathcal{C} \longrightarrow \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$
   defined by the identity of $\mathcal{C}$.
3. There is an isomorphism of categories
   $$
     \mathrm{Fct}(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{C}')^\mathrm{op} \simeq \mathrm{Fct}(\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C}'^{\mathrm{op}}),
     \quad F \longmapsto \mathrm{op} \circ F \circ \mathrm{op}.
   $$

By 1), $\mathrm{op}$ is a functor from $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ to $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$.
So, how could it be identity of $\mathcal{C}$? It perhaps the identity of $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$.
But in this case, in 3), we have $\mathrm{op} \circ F \circ \mathrm{op} = F$
which is not an element of $\mathrm{Fct}(\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C}'^{\mathrm{op}})$.

Comment: The language of categories so much easier when you simply erase the word "contravariant functor". This has been discussed multiple times here already. Your question is an example of which confusions may arise.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg If $F \colon \mathcal{C} \longrightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and
$G \colon \mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op} \longrightarrow \mathcal{E}$ are two (covariants) functors, what is the meaning of $G \circ F$?

Comment: It is not defined. Why should it be? The domain of G is not the target of F. But you can do G composed with F^op for example, and also G^op composed with F.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg So if $G$ is the covariant functor $\mathrm{op}_{\mathcal{B}} \colon \mathcal{B}^{\mathrm{op}} \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}^{\mathrm{op}}$, we can't write $G \circ F$
(where $F \colon \mathcal{A} \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is a covariant functor),
but if $G$ is the contravariant functor $\mathrm{op}_{\mathcal{B}} \colon \mathcal{B} \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}^{\mathrm{op}}$, then we can write $G \circ F$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any category $\mathbf{C}$, there is the functor $\text{op}_\mathbf{C}\colon\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}^\text{op}$ sending each object to itself (as the objects of a category and its opposite category are the same!), and sending any morphism $f\colon C\to D$ to the corresponding unique $f^\text{op}\colon D\to C$. While it is identity on objects, it is not that on morphisms (unless you only have identity morphisms in your category). We can then consider the functor $\text{op}_{\mathbf{C}^\text{op}}\colon\mathbf{C}^\text{op}\to\mathbf{C}$, and compose this with our previous functor and these satisfy $\text{op}_{\mathbf{C}^\text{op}}\circ\text{op}_\mathbf{C}=1_\mathbf{C}$ and $\text{op}_\mathbf{C}\circ\text{op}_{\mathbf{C}^\text{op}}=1_{\mathbf{C}^\text{op}}$. If there is even one non-identity morphism in $\mathbf{C}$, then $\text{op}_\mathbf{C}$ is not the identity functor.

How the claim in Kashiwara-Schapira should be read is $F\mapsto \text{op}_{\mathbf{C}'}\circ F\circ\text{op}_{\mathbf{C}^\text{op}}$, as this is a composite $$\mathbf{C}^\text{op}\xrightarrow{\text{op}_{\mathbf{C}^\text{op}}}\mathbf{C}\xrightarrow{F}\mathbf{C}'\xrightarrow{\text{op}_{\mathbf{C}'}}\mathbf{C}'^\text{op}.$$ What probably confused you is that they denote each of those opposite functors by $\text{op}$ without mentioning the category (as is usually the case). I'll let you figure out its inverse functor yourself to confirm this is indeed an isomorphism! :)